# On whom is the onus of finding a duplicate of a question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I've left a couple of comments on a question, in which the person asking the question states:

> I'm aware that this is a fairly common question but it seems like the answer is always to include a hard-coded height. I would like to avoid this because while that was a perfectly fine solution for the desktop styling this is intended to be displayed on mobile devices and as such I'd like it to be a bit more responsive than a hard-coded height.

This, to my mind, demonstrates an attempt (however cursory) at finding existing duplicates, but finding them inapplicable to the stated problem raised in the question itself.

The following conversation was raised in the comments to that question, between another user (who remains anonymous because this isn't a witch-hunt), myself and the OP of the question (note that there are other comments interspersed, but excised for brevity):

> This is a duplicate of so many questions. - UserOne
>
> @UserOne you're right, the question is probably amongst the most common on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find one that worked for my situation (no hard-coded height). I'd be thrilled with a link to an answered question that does, though! =) - OP
>
> @UserOne: so vote to close as such.<sup>1</sup> - Me
>
> When you're asking a question you should search for duplicates, not rely on others to do so. – UserOne
>
> ...
>
> @UserOne Not to repeat myself but I did. I could not find any that replicated this question even though there are hordes that bear superficial similarities. You clearly feel it's a duplicate, however, so I was asking you to post a link to one – that way we could have this question removed for being redundant or have a permanent link for folks such as myself that couldn't find it. – OP
>
> @UserOne: as the person that stated that this "*is a duplicate of so many questions*" the onus is on you to find a duplicate, and vote to close as such, otherwise your comment adds nothing but noise.<sup>1</sup> - Me
>
> @Me Feel free to disagree if you want, my comment is not noise. It lets the asker know that the answer is out there on this site if they search for it. – UserOne

Clearly UserOne disagrees with me, which is fine; but it has left me wondering: we like that someone asking a question researches first, the OP here demonstrates (at least cursory, and non-productive) research effort. This user has left a comment which s/he feels appropriate stating that there are duplicates, but chooses not to point them out to the OP, or to others in the community.

This *feels*, to me, a dismissive action; it provides no help to anyone and seems to be equivalent to a dismissive "go look again, properly this time," hence my reaction ("*the onus is on [the commenter] to find the duplicate*") and point it/them out; otherwise the comment is simply noise. Plus the ability to flag questions as duplicates (I *think*, it's a long time since I've had to use flags for that) and vote-to-close as duplicate leads me to believe that it's the duty of the commenter.

My question, then: in this situation, is the onus, to find the duplicate, on the person asking the question to go look *again* for duplicate(s), or on the person leaving the comment that duplicates exist?

---

1. there was more to this comment, directed at the OP, but irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You could have commented: *@UserOne Strange, I'm sure you are right but I can't find the correct dupe.* problem solved...

Comment: As an addendum, the question under discussion is a duplicate of one of the most viewed questions of the tag, already sporting about **100** duplicates.

Comment: @rene: what problem does that solve, exactly?

Comment: @DavidThomas It tries to trick the commenter in presenting a duplicate to you showing off his/her search skills.... that only works if you are the higher rep though...

Comment: @rene: possibly, but given the commenter's apparent belief that it's not their job to find the duplicate, I'm not convinced that would have solved the problem. Though I admire your attempted solution. :)

Comment: I would've just flagged the original "This is a duplicate of so many questions." comment as not constructive.

Comment: I read this question title in the Hot Meta Posts sidebar a little too quickly....

Comment: @Milo: if it involved seeing an 'a' in the, uh, wrong place I honestly don't want to know...

Comment: The onus should be on the technology underpinning each SE site.  If it cannot accurately detect probable duplicates based upon the subject and content of a new question, then a critical failure has already occurred.  It's unreasonable to expect anyone else to successfully use the platform's search features and algorithms to track down a duplicate if/when the platform itself has failed to do so.

Comment: the first comment of `UserOne` is as useful as somehow answering `Yes` to the question `Do you have the time?`

Comment: Next time someone ask me if I have the time, I'll answer "This is a duplicate of so many questions."

Comment: In this particular case, it seems like the OP just unfortunately framed it as a duplicate, but his question is NOT a duplicate if he has searched the similar questions and none of them answer his actual question, which is how to do a non-hard-coded value.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Flag UserOne's comment(s) as non-constructive. Once deleted, take yours down and flag the OP's as obsolete, or ask them to delete themselves. I suppose if they make a habit of this sort of pointless "I know of a positive contribution I could make, but I won't, because you should" teasing, they should probably get a talking-to from a diamond.

You can't stop them from downvoting, of course, and you specifically want them to VtC if at all possible, but commenting that a question is definitely a dupe, without saying which one, is the opposite of helpful. Especially in this case, where it wastes time from everyone who tries to find the dozens of questions that are supposedly trivial duplicates and doesn't come up with any.

On the other hand, commenting that a question is *likely* a dupe *could* be helpful, if it reminds someone with the needed knowledge to do a fuller search and track down which. This is not that case.

Comment: The post *isn't* unconstructive.  It is informing the post author of problems with the post that they should correct.  Telling someone that they have a problem, even if you don't actually fix the problem for them, is still constructive.  Without the comment, the OP would simply be unaware of the problems with his own question, and therefore be unable to do anything about it.

Comment: @canon If the comment is *incorrect*, then by all means address that problem.  Reply and state your conflicting viewpoint if you disagree with it.  The fact that you think that it's wrong doesn't make it not constructive or meriting deletion.  As for what use it serves, it provides feedback to the author that there is a problem with their post, feedback that they can potentially use to improve the post, or feedback that they can ignore.  Either way, that's up to them.  Silencing people from providing feedback is simply not constructive.

Comment: @canon Again, if you feel that the author wouldn't have been able to find a working solution with any reasonable amount of research effort, you are more than welcome to provide that feedback.  Informing someone that their question has problems isn't universally prohibited because it's possible that in some cases they might be wrong.  If you think a *particular* piece of feedback is wrong, then say so, don't assume that nobody should be providing any negative feedback *ever*.

Comment: @canon So your response to "this question didn't do sufficient research effort" is to do the OP's research for them, and not tell them that they did anything wrong.  This is actively encouraging them to *not* do research in the future, because they know that someone else will just do it for them if the post the question without performing even cursory research.  Again, if you think that the question *did* perform sufficient research, then you're just saying that this comment is incorrectly evaluating this post, not that comments saying thinks like that are inherently problematic.

Comment: @canon As I say in my answer, the only way to *close* a question as a duplicate is to provide the duplicate.  Closing a question is radically different from just posting a comment to provide feedback.  It's actively inhibiting anyone else from answering.  The fact that closure requires more than just one person thinking it's a duplicate, without actually providing one, is quite reasonable.  Asserting that someone cannot say that a post isn't sufficiently researched without doing all of that person's research for them is very different.

Comment: @canon The fact that someone else doesn't want to take the time to do the research that the post other was obligated to do before asking the question on behalf of the question author, *particularly* if they know that finding the information is extremely easy, seems entirely reasonable to me.  How else will people learn to do research if you always do it for them without any expectation of them doing it themselves?  You assume the commented couldn't find a duplicate.  Perhaps they found one in a few seconds and that is how they knew that the OP could have found it just as easily?

Comment: @canon I have said several times, that if you feel a comment is incorrect, you can reply to indicate that you feel it is incorrect, adding whatever evidence you would like.  Flagging a comment for being "incorrect" is just going to end up with it being declined.  Comments aren't deleted by a mod for being wrong.  And the idea that making a comment like this is universally inappropriate just because there is a possibility that they will sometimes be incorrect sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @canon You don't have to look *everywhere*.  You don't need to prove that it is impossible for you to find the information, just that you don't need to prove that God doesn't exist.  You merely need to explain what you have done, where you have looked, what problems you've had with the information that you have found, why it has not worked, etc.  You don't need to prove that your question isn't a duplicate, just that you weren't able to find one.  *Stating* that you couldn't find a duplicate, or that you did your research, is very different from *demonstrating* that you did your research.

Comment: @canon Which is a sign that the comment may have been wrong in this instance.  That doesn't make such comments universally inappropriate.  Of course, it's also possible that while the OP demonstrated some research effort, the commenter felt it wasn't *sufficient*.  Without context, I couldn't say if he is right or wrong.  It's also possible that the solutions he found do solve his problem, or that he failed to adequately explain why what he found isn't working for him.

Comment: Wow, what a discussion. Someone should invent a chat feature... oh, wait...

Comment: @Servy: I realized (and edited in) something that may clarify the issue here: not only is the comment not helpful, it tends to waste time from experienced users by misleading them into thinking there's an easy dupe flag. Its presence therefore actively makes the question more of a drain on site resources.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That is again assuming that the comment is actually *wrong*.  What if it's *not* wrong?  What if I just edited the example to make it crystal clear that the question author didn't actually do any research, there were obvious, trivial to find, and quality duplicates?  You're arguing that because one example might possibly be wrong, it's inappropriate.  Content isn't deleted for being *wrong*.

Comment: @Servy: When it's a comment, it is! But more to the point: in this context, at least one high-rep user spent some time looking for trivial duplicates, and found none. The comment is therefore at best obsolete, but because it's also somewhat rude and will continue to actively worsen the question, non-constructive is a better match. Now, in cases where there is a trivial duplicate that you can find, of course, go ahead and flag the question accordingly; the comment has, however unpleasantly, done some good in the end. But if it doesn't? Out it goes!

Comment: No, comments are *not* to be deleted just because they're factually incorrect.  You trying to prove that it is factually incorrect is therefore an irrelevant point.  It's also not rude at all.  That a comment is *wrong* does not make it *rude* or not constructive.

Comment: "Oh if you had just looked a little bit you would have surely seen an easy duplicate" is a bit rude, especially if it makes no attempt to explain how the looking recommended is different from the looking the OP did. If it's also correct, that can be a net benefit, although not ideal. As far as deleting (now-)wrong comments goes... what exactly do you consider the Obsolete flag for, then? That's explicitly not something that answers or questions get deleted for, ever.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not doing basic research and asking a question with lots of easy to find duplicates would be extremely rude; informing someone that they had done that is not.  If it's incorrect, then its no more incorrect than any other incorrect statement; if someone posts an answer that's wrong do you consider *that* to be rude?  The primary purpose of the obsolete flags is for requests that have since been fulfilled; for example if someone comments that something should be fixed in an edit, and an edit is made to fix it, the comment is obsolete.

Comment: @Servy: My points stand, since the phrasing is relevant and deleting for wrongness at any point still counts. It is possible to politely inform someone that they neglected to look for duplicates, but this wasn't a polite way to do so, since it's *dismissive* rather than *instructive*. And, of course, a comment that is deleted because it is now uselessly outdated is essentially a comment being deleted because it's inapplicable to the current state of the post, which is exactly the case here.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, it is *not* appropriate to delete a comment just because you think that it's wrong.  There is nothing whatsoever in the moderation guidelines indicating that comments that are wrong merit deletion.  You seem to be inventing this out of nowhere.  What's your basis for asserting that its appropriate to flag comments for deletion purely for being factually incorrect?  And I see nothing improper about the way the comment is phrased; it is providing constructive feedback on the quality of the post.  You can agree or disagree with that *opinion*, but that doesn't make it impolite.

Comment: @Servy: I explained both already, multiple times, and have no further clarifications available. I don't understand why you don't consider dismissive phrasing rude, nor why you're defending the sanctity of noisy comments, when those have explicitly and repeatedly been described as second-class citizens that can and will be removed much more eagerly than any other type of post. Nor, of course, do I understand how this counts as constructive; it was merely restating a checklist item the original post explicitly claimed to have addressed. Bare contradiction is (worse than) useless.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't see why you *do* see the post as being rude.  It's clear that the author had no ill intent; he was simply being terse.  Terseness is not at all equal to rudeness.  The comment is also *not* noisy; it's providing feedback to the author.  When someone posts a comment I think is *wrong* I don't immediately flag it for deletion.  If the comment holds no value *even if correct* then it's something that can merit deletion.  That the question *states* it is well researched doesn't mean that *is*, just like even though you say your answer is correct, doesn't mean that it is.

Comment: @Servy: But it's precisely the fact that the comment holds no value even if correct that is so obnoxious here. The author *did* research, or did what they consider to be research; telling them "research!" again is of no possible use! It's that "nuh-uh" impression that is also the source of the rudeness, since it's a flat denial of their claim without engaging with it. Conceivably the comment might be of value to other experienced users, but if it's so obvious as all that, insulting their intelligence by saying "now remember to do your job of hunting basic dupes" doesn't do much good either.

Comment: @NathanTuggy We have been told that the question author *claimed* to have done research.  We have no idea whether or not they did research, or how good of a job they did at demonstrating the research that they did.  The comment is informing the question author that they failed to adequately demonstrate sufficient research, despite their claim of having done some research.  It is feedback on the problems with the question, which is certainly more valuable to the OP than just anonymous downvotes whereby the OP may not realize that the problem was insufficiently demonstrated research.

Comment: @Servy: It may or may not be more valuable to the OP. It is arguably less valuable to everyone else on the site. What's more, by pointing out "inadequately demonstrated research" by way of *no* demonstrated research at all, it at once demonstrates hypocrisy and fails to move the question forward.

Comment: @NathanTuggy When someone is providing feedback on the quality of a question that question is very much targeted at the question author.  It's not there to help everyone else.  It's there so that the question author can improve their question; if they do, then *that* will help future readers.

Comment: @Servy: Downvotes, to which you compared this, and comments on probable dupe-ness, to which this is most similar, are both aimed at least as much at other (especially experienced) users who can use that information to efficiently deal with questions as at the OP.

Comment: @NathanTuggy For votes on the question, that's completely correct, for comments on the question, not so much.  The downvote is there to inform other readers or potential readers that the question is problematic, the comment is there to help the author understand why the question is problematic so they can fix it.

Answer (score 12):

Users asking questions are expected to research their questions before asking them and to search for duplicates before posting.  This is a prominent theme of the help center's pages on how to ask questions.

If a question is not well researched, you should be downvoting it.  That is the appropriate mechanism for indicating that a question's author didn't do sufficient research before asking their question.

The only way to *close* a question *because* it is poorly researched is to find a duplicate and vote to close the question.

So if UserOne wants this question closed, they'll need to find a duplicate to close it against.  If they're fine just downvoting and moving on, that's also their prerogative.  They certainly aren't *obligated* to do the OP's research for them and go out of their way to find a duplicate if they don't want to.

If UserOne wants to leave a comment to go along with their downvote (or even instead of a downvote, I guess) to indicate that the primary problem with the question is a lack of sufficient research, they certainly are welcome to do so, as long as that comment remains constructive and isn't rude/offensive.  They don't have to find a duplicate to vote to close with in order to inform the author that their post lacks sufficient research effort, nor are they prohibited from explaining their downvote in a comment so that the author understands what problem their question has.

Comment: But the comment that "*This is a duplicate of so many questions*" followed by the unwillingness to point out a duplicate feels as if that comment immediately becomes unconstructive, and unnecessarily noisy. I have no issue with the question being placed on hold *as* a duplicate, it's simply the lack of effort, the refusal to help, and perhaps several unwarranted inferences I've drawn from UserOne's comments, that irritates me.

Comment: @DavidThomas And people posting low quality questions and not bothering to do their research before asking is very irritating to me.  It's perfectly fine to tell someone that they didn't do enough research before asking their question.  You are not obligated to do all of their research for them just to tell them that they didn't do enough research to post a question.  Fundamentally it is the author's responsibility to research their question before asking it, not the reader's responsibility to do 100% of their research for them because the question author couldn't be bothered to.

Comment: Seems unconstructive to me too, if that fact was already mentioned in the question. flag as such? The question isn't a duplicate if within the question you *"successfully"* explain why your situation is different from the supposed duplicates.

Comment: But the OP did *state*, albeit perhaps not substantially/sufficiently enough, (as shown in the question) that s/he *did* look for duplicates first, and found them wanting.

Comment: Did he/she explain *why* the duplicates didn't solve the problem? if not, then it's probably still a dupe

Comment: @KevinB So if someone asks, "How do I add two numbers together.  Oh, and I already searched on Google, there were no solutions?" you'll just trust them and assume that there really are no solutions on Google and that they really did do their best to try and find an existing solution?  The fact that someone *says* that they did their research doesn't mean that they actually did it.  And of course if you, as a second reader of the question, feel that the question is a well researched question, you're more than welcome to provide *that* feedback as well, just as another user can say the opposite.

Comment: @Servy no, there has to be a *why* it is different that is substantial enough, though that is of course subjective.

Comment: @DavidThomas And if you sincerely believe that the question was well researched, and that the author really is unable to find the solution to their problem despite doing a reasonable amount of research, you can provide that feedback (in the form of both voting and commenting).  If someone else feels the opposite, they too can provide that feedback.  *Both* are acceptable.

Comment: In that case, as you mention to Kevin, the lack of research is evident from personal knowledge; I'm personally not aware of a duplicate of this question. Hence my asking UserOne to identify one (as did the OP in the comments) in order that it might be closed. As to the level of research undertaken I'm entirely indifferent (though I'd happily use my own dupe-hammer to close if someone raises a reasonable dupe); I am, though, confused by behaviour that leaves critical remarks, assumes no personal responsibility and is simply noisy and unconstructive.

Comment: @DavidThomas One is not obligated to fix all of the problems a post one reads.  If a user instead wants to take the time to inform the author of the post's problems, without taking the time to fix all of them, they can.  It's often an appropriate middle ground between doing nothing and doing everything for them.  It can often be even *more* constructive than just fixing all of the problems with the question as it helps the author learn how to ask better questions in the future.  At the end of the day, that user has no *responsibility* to fix the question.  The question author does.

Comment: @DavidThomas If you, or a question author, consider polite comments indicating problems with a question to be noise, then that's just unfortunate to me, and considering all the complaints that I constantly see about unexplained downvotes and how people want to know what problems their post has that need improvement, it seems that others also feel that its not noise.  If you personally aren't interested in reading about how a post can be improved, then it's probably not worth your time to read comments in general, as that's their primary purpose.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something, I'm genuinely not trying to be obtuse, but while I can accept it's not the *obligation* of the commenter to provide a link to the duplicate question, expecting the person asking the question (who's stated that they've already searched without resolution) to search again without direction seems, *at best*, counter-productive. And I don't see how the comment left in that question could be anything other than noise, in what way is that useful, given that the OP states that s/he had searched already?

Comment: ...Assuming the OP is telling the truth, the comment provides no further assistance as to where these duplicates might be. If the OP is lying about having searched, the s/he's not going to take that information and do anything with it. Without direction *I* can't close the question (without being forced to go search myself). If there'd been a glimmer of information in the comment I'd be happy to close the question. And yes, I could search, but a *quick* (and I do mean a very quick) search didn't yield a dupe for this particular question. So, I fail to see how it was of *any use*.

Comment: I liked Servy's response, that if the commenter does not want to point out the duplicate question to downvote, they are not obligated to.  But I disagree with saying they have a right to vote to close with no evidence.  They should provide at least one example, otherwise we'd have people just saying "Close as dupe" just on their maybe-not-so-clear memories, with no evidence.

Comment: @vapcguy You *can't* VTC as duplicate without providing the duplicate. Feature complete!

Comment: If you're going to comment that something is a duplicate of many questions, look first and provide one.  Otherwise you might be _wrong_... and either way it's not a constructive way to state that you feel it is poorly researched.  `You will find the answer to the question easily if you search [terms]` would be a more constructive way to state it- though again, if it's a trivial search, why not *do* the search?

Comment: Ultimately, this site is supposed to be professionals interacting in a professional way - and so any comment you make should be something you'd similarly make to the person sitting in the next room/cube/office.  `This is a dupe of so many questions...` is unprofessional and rude.

Comment: @Joe At the end of the day it is the responsibility of the person asking the question to do their research before asking their question.  That responsibility does not lie in everyone else to do it for them because they just couldn't be bothered.  Asking questions of other professions, such as your co-workers, without doing any reasonable amount of research first, is not respecting their time.  It is rude an unprofessional.  Informing someone that they have not done their due diligence before asking a question, instead of just doing their work for them, is a professional response.

Comment: @canon I'm merely stating that the person has the right to provide the feecback that he thinks that the question is not well researched.  That feedback can be correct, or it can be incorrect, but he's allowed to provide it either way.  If you disagree, you are *also* allowed to provide *your* feedback.  Regardless of who is right, each person is allowed to state their position.  You do not get to censor someone just because you think they're wrong.

Comment: @Joe, wasting one's workmates' time with a question one should be able to answer oneself is unprofessional and rude. Pointing out rudeness is not in itself rude (though it's certainly easy for it to be done in an uncordial way).

Comment: You both are criticizing the asker - which is fine.  If the question is not thoroughly researched, the question should be.  _That does not make the comment constructive, though._  Two wrongs do not make a right.  Pointing out rudeness is not rude, *unless done rudely*, which that comment certainly was.

Comment: I don't find it to be rude at all, @Joe. It's not especially helpful, but definitely not insulting, discourteous, or offensive.

Comment: @Joe What about it did you find rude?  How would you have phrased the same comment to make it not be rude, in your eyes?

Comment: `This is a duplicate of so many questions.` It is rude because it is condescending - telling a user that already _said_ he looked at duplicates that there are 'so many' duplicates.  It is rude because it is passive - it "attempts" to tell the user that he should do more research, but it doesn't actually say that explicitly.  It instead just says "You're an idiot because you couldn't find the duplicate."  It doesn't actually _help_ the user in any way (thus 'not constructive' at a minimum), and just puts him down.

Comment: I gave an alternate suggestion in an earlier comment: at a minimum, `You will find the answer to the question easily if you search [terms]`.  If the user didn't find the duplicate, and obviously did at least look a _little_ (as the user here clearly did), then perhaps he doesn't know what to search under.  If the user didn't do _any_ research, then something more like `This is a common question; please search StackOverflow for your question and you should find an answer.` would be fine.  That's constructive and direct, not passive and condescending.  (Better still is linking to a dup...)

Comment: @Joe So you think telling someone something that they wouldn't want to hear is rude, no matter how you go about saying it?  That's not how that works.  You can tell someone that they posted a low quality question politely, and you can tell them that they posted a low quality question rudely.  This particularly comment told the author that he posted a low quality question *politely*.  Your example of, "You're an idiot because you couldn't find the duplicate." would be a way of saying the same thing *rudely*.

Comment: @Joe I fail to see how your second example is meaningfully different from the comment discussed here.  Both are passive, neither is directly attacking the author, both are indicating that the question doesn't demonstrate sufficient research effort, etc.  Both comments are quite reasonable.  Neither is in any way offensive or inappropriate.

Comment: Absolutely not.  I posted two examples of how you could provide the same information constructively.  My comment above pretty clearly answers that... The statement as given is basically immature - it's stated in effectively a mocking fashion.  It's not something, exactly as stated, that I'd expect to hear from a colleague.

Comment: Then it sounds like we just disagree; but all I can say is that my example is something I'd say to someone in my professional environment.  The first would be rude in my professional environment.  (This is setting aside the particulars of _this_ question.)

Comment: @Joe It sounds like you're reading it in an offensive tone because you want it to be offensive, instead of simply reading it in a neutral tone, as there is every indication was the author's intent, given the second comment quoted.  I could read your second example comment in an offensive tone if I was really trying to, and assume that the author was being immature and mocking me.  There is no reason to believe that the comment in question isn't sincerely indicating a problem with the question so that the author can fix it, any more than in your comment.

Comment: Personally, since the asker clearly *did* do the research, to the best of his or her ability, I find it hard to see the response as anything but condescending.  It can be difficult to find an existing question amongst dozens or hundreds of similar but distinct questions, and "try harder" is not a helpful suggestion.  (My opinion may be biased by the fact that in my experience, the person claiming that the question is a duplicate probably just hasn't read it carefully enough to understand that it *is* different.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't see how any of us can even have a strong opinion on this specific example without even being able to see the question.  Perhaps it was well researched, perhaps it wasn't.  We simply don't have enough information.  If the question was well researched, then that simply means that this one comment is *wrong*, not *inappropriate*.  If you see a comment that you think is factually incorrect, respond appropriately.

Comment: @Servy: right or wrong, it isn't helpful - it isn't *actionable*.  Unless you assume the OP is lying (which is *inherently* rude) they already tried to find an answer and failed.  Perhaps that's because they are incompetent at research, but even if that's true, how does pointing it out help?  It doesn't seem any different to me than making the (often true!) observation that if someone was better at programming they wouldn't need to ask for help.  True but unhelpful.

Comment: @HarryJohnston If a question author didn't actually spend any, or enough, time searching for a solution, and simply asked the question on SO without doing their due diligence, then it most certainly *is* actionable.  If the author did do sufficient research, and still couldn't find it, then the comment is merely wrong, and the advice is indeed not actionable, so yes, it most certainly matters if it's right or wrong.  In one case it's actionable, and in the other it's not.

Comment: @HarryJohnston It is not "inherently rude" to tell someone that their question doesn't meet the minimum standards for asking a question on this site.  Asking a question that doesn't meet the minimum standards of the site is rude; informing them of their mistake is helping them by informing them both what they did wrong and what they need to do to fix it.  Again, this is assuming the commentor is correct in his assumption about the level of research done.  If he's wrong, then he's not being rude, he's just wrong in his advice.

Comment: I didn't say it was inherently rude to tell someone that they've made a mistake, I said it was inherently rude to assume someone is lying.  Now, if the OP *was* lying then the comment might indeed be helpful - but why worry about helping someone who lied to us?   ... well, unless you're Dr. House I suppose. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston All I'm saying is that the feedback that the quesiton lacks sufficient effort is valuable feedback if correct, and if incorrect, merely wrong, and not rude or inappropriate.  It could be that the user doesn't believe the OP when they merely state that they did research (despite the fact that question guidelines say that they need to *demonstrate* their research, not just say that they did it), or they could believe that the OP did do research, but feel that they didn't do enough.

Comment: A fair point.  It is possible that it is the tone of the comments that annoys me most; "UserOne" is basically claiming to be so awesome that he knows, not suspects mind you but *knows* that the question is a duplicate, without needing to go to the trouble of actually finding one.  I *might* have said something like "I'm sure I've seen this before, are you sure that you've looked thoroughly?"  But YMMV.  (It does seem to me that the OP pointing out specifically how his question is different to the others that he found demonstrates research.  I'm not sure what else they could do?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've seen many hundreds of questions that I *knew* I could find a duplicate for without even needing to look (often because I know I've answered the question personally).  Without knowing what the actual question is, and the experience of the user, we obviously can't know if this user did know that there were duplicates.  The idea that it could happen is most certainly not out of the question.

Comment: **"If a question is not well researched, you should be downvoting it."** I wish that was plastered on every single page. Unfortunately pitty upvotes often undo my work.

Comment: @KevinB Sadly this question seems to be demonstrating that most people  have no expectation of research for questions, to the point that they're going to actively go out of their way to suppress the built in tools designed to encourage it.  I'm not particularly *surprised*, after all having tons more low quality duplicate and trivially researchable questions is by far the easiest way to get reputation, so there's an incentive to encourage people to ask more and more of that low quality content, but it still is disappointing.

Comment: I think it's more of a perception issue. How much research should be considered well researched? From my perspective, most of the questions that get asked now days are poorly researched, simply because I can answer them myself by doing a little bit of research. That wasn't the case when i first started answering questions here years ago.

Comment: @KevinB That is certainly an issue, but on this question we're seeing the majority of people say that it's universally wrong to tell someone that their question isn't well researched; that providing that feedback is inherently rude and inappropriate, regardless of how it's actually phrased, and regardless of how much research is actually done by the question author.  To me that is completely absurd, regardless of how much research one feels is actually appropriate for an SO question.

Comment: @Servy: I've known a question was a duplicate before too, but I will actually go to the trouble of *finding* said duplicate rather than just assuming I'm remembering correctly.  Occasionally I've even discovered that the question I was thinking of was *not* really a duplicate, because of some subtle distinction I'd overlooked.  But in any case I don't think most people are saying that you shouldn't ever say anything, just that you shouldn't say it as rudely as the example in this case.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm over-reacting again, sorry.  It is true that the way the comments in this example are phrased seem rude to me, but of course that's subjective.  It presumably depends on your cultural background as well as personal preference.  (I'm understating things; the posted exchange doesn't just seem rude, it positively enrages me.  But that's an emotional response, not a rational one.)

Comment: @KevinB: are you sure you're not underestimating your own research abilities?  I mean, I assume you're not talking about questions within your own field of expertise (since otherwise the only "good" question would be one that nobody can answer!) but even so you've had years of practice at researching computing questions.  Finding the answer might not always be as straightforward for a newcomer as it seems to you.  There's also [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285562/886887); that an answer exists outside of SO doesn't mean that it would be a bad idea to have an answer here as well.

Comment: Exactly, that's why i say it's a perception problem. I don't go around downvoting everything i see, it's just difficult for me to now look at a question and judge the amount of research that was put into it, so i tend to  instead judge based on other factors first, such as clarity.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I see numerous questions a day where simply throwing the exact literal text of the question into google leading to a quality, correct, and detailed answer.  It doesn't get much easier than that.  And I can't possibly see what you consider rude about the comments posted.  It's indicating that there is a woeful lack of research, it states its facts plainly.  Terseness is not at all rudeness.  How would *you* phrase the same information in a way that you consider to be not rude?

Comment: @Servy: that still doesn't make the question a duplicate IMO unless there's already an answer *on SO* [as per this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285562/886887) but that's a different question.  FWIW I'm equally baffled as to why you *don't* think the original comments are rude, but I'm guessing this is a more-or-less stereotypical American v. British thing.  (I'm actually from New Zealand, not Britain, but whatever.)  I did suggest an alternative earlier: "I'm sure I've seen this before, are you sure that you've looked thoroughly?"  (The difference being that it admits I might be mistaken.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston The commenters couldn't vote to *close* the question unless they find a duplicate on SO; that doesn't mean that there isn't an onus on the question author to do their research (both on and off of the site), or that there is anything wrong with informing the author that they didn't do sufficient research.  As far as your wording, I don't see how waffling ones words has anything to do with rudeness.  The original comment is implicitly stating that one person's opinion on the quality of the research; stating that explicitly, while not wrong, is most certainly not *necessary*.

Comment: That something is not necessary does not necessarily make it unwise.  (Personally, I'm not convinced that the original comments really were intended as a statement of opinion.  But I don't suppose it matters.)

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to answer the heading question, without reference to the particulars of this case.
The particulars of this case, are well answered already.

**On whom is the onus of finding a duplicate of a question?**

This is the wrong way to think:

**The onus is on the whole community to make the site a better place**
Each person brings their skills to the table, some people are good at editing for clarity, some people are good at finding tags to be burninated, and some people are good at finding duplicate questions.

Yes, it is nice if the question asker can just write clearly, and doesn't use bad tags, and ask questions that have not been asked before, but because we all have varying strengths and weaknesses, odds are that in at least one of those (example) categories someone else in the community could do it better. So that person (who is better), can, will and should do what they can to help improve the site.

This is why we can do things other sites can't, like edit each others posts

**The onus is on us all, to help each other out -- not to point fingers and blame.**

Comment: No. Unless I'm being paid for it, I will apply my personal criteria.  If I think I'm being used, eg. as a Google search slave or debugging engine, I will react appropriately.  Effective cooperation works fine as long as the other parties don't take the piss.  Each person brings their skills to the table, and one of those skills is conning other people to do work for them for free.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not entirely sure what I said that made you think that I am saying people shouldn't to there best to find duplicates. I'm saying they should. But I am also saying that other people can do it better (except for that one guy on the site who is the current best at finding duplicates in that area.). The onus is on everyone, **including** the asker.

Comment: @MartinJames That attitude is becoming so prevalent here, and I'm getting so sick of it! You may think a guy is trying to make you a Google slave, but so what? You know how to not let that affect you? Ignore it! I get so tired of people around being so high and mighty. Maybe the guy asking is being a jerk or lazy, but maybe he's someone genuinely in need of help and willing to work for his answers. It's like we forget that this site exists to **SERVE** people. I agree with Oxinabox. This site exists to help people, and being a jerk to a jerk (who may not actually be a jerk) isn't helpful.

Comment: @mbm29414 The site *doesn't* exist to serve other people.  It is not a place for people to just get free programming work done because some people are suckers and giving it away for free.  It is a place designed to create a repository of useful programming knowledge readily available to the entire world.  Having quality questions with quality answers serves that purpose.  Answering the same duplicate question hundreds of times or doing Google searches for people who couldn't be bothered to utilize the amazing resources *already provided by others on the site* is *not* serving that purpose.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, but that's a foolish false dichotomy. "Useful programming knowledge readily available to the entire world" == "existing to serve people". I'm not arguing in favor of poor questions or letting people get their work done for free. I'm arguing that we have mechanisms to appropriately handle those cases and being a jerk about doesn't serve anyone's (legitimate) purpose.

Comment: @mbm29414 I suppose I should have been more precise; the site doesn't exist just to serve the one person asking the question at the expense of everyone else, which appears to be what you're asserting.  Informing someone politely that they have not done sufficient research before asking their question is *not* being a jerk.  It is providing constructive feedback on the quality of the question.  There are rude ways to say it and appropriate ways to say it, but the inherent act of telling someone that their question is not up to the site's standards is not inherently rude or inappropriate.

Comment: @mbm29414 You're quite right that we have mechanisms for dealing with poor quality questions that don't meet the site's standards.  And one of the primary mechanisms in place is to comment on the question to politely inform the question author that their question has problems, and to explain what those problems are (in this case, insufficient research).  That is (one of) the appropriate mechanisms for dealing with this type of problem.  Asserting that one is not allow to use comments to inform a question author of problems with their question is just absurd.  **It's why comments exist.**

Comment: @MartinJames You are free to decline to answer any question you like, especially ones you feel are lacking in effort. As a member of this community graciously hosted by the StackExchange team, though, you are still expected to adhere to the guidelines and rules set forth by them. This answer is *spot on* for what's expected of us as members of this community. If you don't like that as a general principle, maybe this community is not really a good fit for you, and that's okay. And if you only feel that way about specific questions, don't forget the Be Nice policy. Just ignore them and move on.

Comment: @jpmc26 The SE guidelines include extensive information about what makes a quality question.  When a question violates those rules and guidelines, for example by not doing reasonable research effort before asking the question, the community is expected to respond using a number of different tools that their disposal to encourage quality content.  One of those tools is to comment indicating the problems in the question.  To just say that one should ignore any question they don't like is in fact *contrary* to SE's guidelines.  The community is *not* expected to ignore problems in questions.

Comment: @Servy You aren't actually paying attention to my comments. I'm completely in favor of corrective actions and comments. I like the site being clean and functional and valuable. I'm objecting to people who feel it's their duty to be **jerks** or **obtuse** while doing this. In the OP's example, the commenter made a jerky comment in passing and wouldn't put forth any effort to substantiate his claim. That's irritating and unhelpful. And it doesn't lead to better questions **OR** answers.

Comment: @mbm29414 No, there is nothing whatsoever inappropriate about informing someone that they didn't do enough research.  It did so politely and without being insulting (unlike your tone here, for example).  But I suppose I'll humor you; how do you feel he should have phrased the comment for you to not consider it inappropriate?

Comment: @Servy First, I'm not being insulting. Unless using words based on their dictionary definition is insulting. Even you agreed you were imprecise in your first comment, and you didn't correctly represent my position in your second. In response to your question: if I make a claim of "duplicate", I provide the link to the duplicate question. The OP has already asserted their attempt to find an answer and the inability to do so. Claiming this to be false in a comment without substantiating the claim (by linking to said duplicate) is - at best - lazy and - at worst - arrogantly condescending.

Comment: @Servy "the community is expected to respond" Exactly, and what this answer says. Martin James was, in opposition to this answer, expressing frustration that he feels he is "being used" when doing so. He doesn't like putting forth the effort he feels the OP should have done, so he's better off just moving on if he wants to participate in this community. In this specific example, it's not useful to make claims that the OP didn't do enough research and then refuse to confirm that with your own research. At that point, it's an unfounded claim, and you're better off saying nothing.

Comment: @mbm29414 So you have no problem with someone being too lazy to do any reasonable amount of research before asking a question, but you feel that it's inappropriate for anyone to claim that the question author was being lazy when asking their question because doing so is being lazy?  Do you not realize the contradiction there.  You're criticizing someone for being lazy because they criticized someone for being lazy, asserting that criticizing someone for being lazy is wrong.  Take your own advice.

Comment: @Servy I'm loving the straw men you're setting up and calling "mbm29414". :-) Seriously, though, you're either being intentionally obtuse or really aren't paying attention to the specifics of this question. The OP stated that they had done research and found similar questions that didn't answer their particular need. The commenter said "it's a dupe". The OP said, "I checked and couldn't find one; do you mind telling me where the answer is?" The commenter said, "if you're not lazy, you can find it." At some point, don't we have to take the word of others on this site?

Comment: @mbm29414 If you think the comment is wrong then you can think that he's wrong, and you're more than welcome to indicate that you think that the question is well researched if you would like.  Saying that he doesn't have the right to express his view that he feels that the question isn't well researched isn't a valid concern though.  You don't have to agree with him, but you do have to respect his right to that viewpoint.  Whether the comment is correct or not is something that I haven't even expressed a view on.  Without seeing the specific question, there's no way for me to know he is right.

Comment: @Servy Hmm, and here I thought we were allowed to have opinions on SE. Weird. Guess I was mistaken about that! So, we're expected to make valid/valuable contributions, but I'm not allowed to say I think he gave an invalid/worthless contribution? And how exactly have I not respected his right to offer a worthless contribution? We're discussing opinions here. **My opinion** is that his comment is "noise" (like the OP thinks, too). **My opinion** is that his comment is smug and unhelpful. None of those opinions remove (or even attempt to remove) his right to his worthless comment.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for your comments here. I hope a lot of SE users have your perspective about the site.

Comment: @mbm29414 Just because you think that the comment is wrong doesn't make it rude, it doesn't make it insulting, it doesn't make it inappropriate, it doesn't mean it should be flagged or deleted, it doesn't make it smug.  If you think that it's wrong, then you can say that it's wrong.  Saying that the comment is in any way violating policies, meriting deletion, etc. just because you think that it's wrong is simply incorrect.  Nor is your behavior of insulting him as a person for holding a viewpoint that you disagree with a constructive way to evaluate the comment.

Comment: @mbm29414 Oh, and how you can know that the comment is wrong or incorrect without even seeing the post in question is beyond me.  You may certainly have your suspicions, but without all of the facts and context *none* of us can know whether his evaluation of the post is in fact reasonable.

Comment: @Servy I'm starting to think you have a different definition of words than I do..... I'm trying but failing to see how I insulted him as a person. Everything I've said was about his behavior and/or comment. Also, you keep assuming that I'm saying things I haven't said. Again, setting up straw men. How I can make a decision about the comment has everything to do with the information that the OP has posted here. Believe it or not, I actually trust people on this site when they make reasonable assertions.

Comment: @Servy Let me be ***excruciatingly*** clear: I **do not** think the comment should be deleted. I **do** agree with Oxinabox that said comment does a poor job of reflecting the values this site **ought** to have, namely, looking out for the quality of the site and serving as a helpful resource to others. I **do** think that comments such as "This is a duplicate, but, even though you've indicated you can't find the duplicate, I'm not going to help you" are unhelpful at best. Does that help you see my perspective?

Answer (score -23):

Everything is a duplicate, search for a math problem and you'll find a thousand solutions, but a thousand solutions don't necessarily mean a solution for a particular person. What people tend to forget is that we are individuals with different comprehension abilities.

Just because you can solve x^2=10x-2x^2+139 and provide a solution for it doesn't mean that other people who see your solution for that particular problem will understand it.
Some people will need extra help such as what the different letters and numbers represent.

To point a person back to a "provided" solution that they already have seen and tried to understand doesn't really help that person in anyway. 
Duplicates have a purpose, they provide information differently and that is what makes it great, sometimes you need a "new perspective" to understand something.

The person who posted a duplicate question and admitted to posting a duplicate because of the fact that he didn't understand the original or other duplicates, obviously is justified. You aren't him and you can't know what he understands and doesn't understand.

I myself have to search and looked at 10-25 duplicates sometimes and even then I may not be able to solve my problem. Duplicates have a purpose as long as they aren't identical and they help a lot of people.

Pointing fingers on the other hand doesn't accomplish anything, if you aren't up to task to go through with finding out whether a post is truly a duplicate, don't "burden" yourself with the task of it.

Imagine a judge sentencing a person to prison even though the judge never has seen this person, or heard of him... **Don't be that judge!**

Comment: Having 1000 duplicates of the same question is bad. Having 10 is ok, its a scale thing. But if you *are* going to post something that you know is considered a duplicate, you need to do a good job explaining what didn't make sense with those answers. Otherwise, we would just be parroting the same information, which is why we close duplicates (to prevent such parroting).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That is true, however we didn't go from Cart to car by sticking with one type of cart, with each cart a new piece was added(not really) and evetually that is what led to the cars we have today.
Duplication is, it's what leads to solutions and **better** solutions and progress. There are obvious answers such as 5+5=10, easy to understand right, well, there are those who don't know what 5+5 equals to...  But all in all, I agree, somewhat. As long as the duplicates aren't Identical I don't see the issue on how many there are.

Comment: Without going in circles, the key is that you *explain why those solutions didn't work/make sense*. By doing so, you've made your question not a duplicate! Just saying, I didn't get X solution, or Y post didn't work for me isn't enough (and few posters make even that effort). You *have to be specific*.

Comment: Of course, I completely agree on that, you can't ask a question which you've already seen a dozen of answers to and hope somebody gives you an answer which you can understand.

Comment: "Imagine a judge sentencing a person to prison even though the judge never has seen this person, or heard of him... "   It's called "In absentia" and it's a perfectly valid part of law in many locations.  You don't need to see someone ("justice is blind") or have previously heard of them to come to a conclusion as to whatever they're accused of transgresses some point of law.

Comment: When I said "never have heard of" I meant it in every way. judged without the judge even reading your file to know what you are accused of.
And it's highly arguable whether justice is "blind" or not, but that isn't the point here :P