# Why can we not post asking for resources for learning on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377684/does-anyone-know-any-good-sources-for-learning-how-to-using-retrofit-with-androi) on Stack Overflow asking for some resources to start learning Retrofit. I had a feeling I was going to get some negative responses saying that this is not a specific question, this site is not for these questions, etc. It seems like people on Stack Overflow do not like these "where should I start?" style posts.

Stack Overflow represents the congregation of programming knowledge. Knowing where to start as a budding developer is an important first step in learning something new. I guess I just want to open up discussion about these kind of posts:

1. Why are they frowned upon?
2. What's wrong with letting people
   post these types of questions?
3. How is it a detriment to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason they are frowned upon is because, by virtue of being third-party resources, Stack Overflow has no control over them and therefore cannot guarantee their availability, reliability or currency. An answer becomes useless the moment a link breaks and the information is no longer retrievable (archive notwithstanding). Furthermore, such questions can and do attract spam answers.

The mission of SO is to build a central programming knowledgebase. The best way to ensure that this knowledge remains available for as long as SO continues to exist, is to host it on the site itself (and even in the unlikely event of SO itself going under for some reason, [we have data dumps of all our content](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) so not all will be lost). Questions whose answers simply consist of links to other resources over which we have no control run foul of this mission.

Comment: Besides these are questions easily answerable by a simple search. Why should anyone do the search for another?

Comment: The idea is that questions on Stack Overflow can serve as a centralized collection of links. You can search the web, but what are the chances you'll find all the best resources in a single SERP? Having them all in the same page would make things much easier - you'd just have to find that one page.