# Where would I ask a question regarding finding information about Unit Testing a specific language?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just started my journey on the road to programming in C# and ASP.NET and wanted to know where I could find resources involving unit testing these languages. Would I post a question like this in Stack Overflow?

Comment: see also: [Why can we not post asking for resources for learning on StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285561/why-can-we-not-post-asking-for-resources-for-learning-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Search engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't post questions asking for resource recommendations on a topic (like unit testing) on Stack Overflow. They are [explicitly off topic.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Google is a good first choice for finding resources - using, say,

> `c# unit testing`

or

> `asp-net unit testing`

as queries.

*Specific programming questions* about issues related to unit testing C# and ASP.NET are totally fine on SO, of course. Indeed, [there already are plenty of them!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+unit-testing)