# DROP TAG [table];

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Hey Green slim mutated Dragonite, [image: tag burninated], I have something that you might want to take a look at (which I saw when asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379315/table-column-priorities)):

[table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table): Its [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/table/info) suggests *"DO NOT USE THIS TAG"* and it has many questions attached to it. I think this should be your main meal.

And for dessert, you can taste the [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable), whose [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatable/info) states: *The term "datatable" is ambiguous*.

I see you are not in mood for these tags, what about [positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning)? Its [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/positioning/info) is similar to the others.

Comment: @bluefeet close catch. However, in here I say that once it's wiki says not use it, it should be deleted (I am not discussing whether child tags should be created). If it's not, then more users will use it, because "they didn't see it", etc. [off-topic: I just saw your pic, you are truly bluefeet, awesome!].

Comment: I suggest "DROP TAG [table];" for the title

Comment: @BhargavRao [status-complete] is a bit premature as already there have been new posts and therefore the tag info has not yet been deleted. It might takes days for it to go quiet! But thanks anyway.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩, I cleared it yesterday just before 3UTC, thinking it would kill the tag, but apparently it didn't. I've been playing wackamole with it since then. I'm waiting till Shog is online so that he can kill the tag. (I _can_ rename it to something useless, and therefore kill it immediately, but I thought that the tag deserved a more peaceful death)..

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩, it is now done. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/table/info. Thank you so much for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you point out that there's pretty widespread ([though not universal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299779/3093387)) sentiment that [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) is a bad tag, I don't think the correct choice would be burnination, aka removing [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) from all the questions that have it.

To see why, consider the following excerpt from the tag wiki:

> **For HTML Questions:** Please use the [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) tag.
>
> **For Lua variable type**: Please use the [lua-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-table) tag.
>
> **For the CSS `display` property** (includes table display values): Please use the [css-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-tables) tag.
>
> **For the C# Datatable class:** Please use the [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) tag.
>
> **For the jQuery DataTables plugin:** Please use the [jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) tag.
>
> **For Java Persistent API `@Table` annotation:** Please use one of [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa)-related tags.
>
> **For Excel Questions:** Please use one of [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)-related tags.
>
> **For [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) `data.table` questions:** Please use the [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) tag.

To me, this means the way to deal with [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) would be a retagging (and cleanup) operation at a massive scale -- there are currently more than 23,000 questions tagged, and for each one somebody would need to manually determine the correct retagging decision. Note that [automated retagging tools can't conditionally retag based on other tags present on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287681/retag-r-questions-misstaged-with-tagdataframes#comment163259_287681). To me, manually cleaning up 23,000 questions doesn't really seem feasible. Even if it were, the effort would be better spent elsewhere on the site.

I have a similar opinion about your other two proposed burninations. For instance, [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) should really be retagged based on whether the question is about a .NET class or about a JSF UI component or about a component in Wicket or about a package in R; manually retagging more than 10,000 such questions sounds infeasible.

Comment: @pnuts Wow -- super impressive progress!