# Why was this discussion [table]d?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across the [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) tag for the first time, and noticed, as I'm sure many of you who have heard this discussion before know, that its tag description says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG; it is ambiguous."

An answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304218/drop-tag-table) from Sep '15 cites the other tags mentioned in the tag description and 23,000 questions tagged [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) as a reason to keep it hanging around.

Answers to [the question that the previous one is marked as a duplicate of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299728/are-we-still-trying-to-axe-the-table), from Jul '15, present mostly good arguments for getting rid of it.

Now, [there are around 2000 open questions tagged table](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btable%5D+closed%3A0), which seems at least manageable for a concentrated retagging effort. ([Almost all](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btable%5D+closed%3A0+html) should be tagged with [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) instead, or Closed.) The weirdest thing, perhaps, is that there is an almost-3-year gap between Dec 8, '15 and the next question tagged [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), which was posted two hours ago.

1. Is the only reason to keep [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) around to point other people towards the tag they should be using? Is that a good enough reason to keep it?
2. What happened to the other ~21,000 questions tagged [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table)?
3. Why were there no questions tagged [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) for almost three years? This might not be a super great question, but it seems very unlikely to me that nobody was using it for that long, and then there are 3 just today.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the answer from Sep '15. There's a difference between "burninate" and "retag them all" - burning the tag is a developer tool that literally just deletes the tag off all the questions which still have it. That's a fairly destructive thing to do, and doesn't at all help those questions which need some other table tag. Presumably the thousands of questions that no longer have it have since been retagged with something more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding the answer from Sep '15, and I am aware of the difference -- it says, "To me, manually cleaning up 23,000 questions doesn't really seem feasible." It couldn't be burninated because too many questions used it and would need retagging before the tag was done away with. I am surprised that ~21,000 of them have been retagged. But, since they apparently have been, the question is _can we finish cleaning them and get rid of this bad tag_?

Comment: Just to further rehash for clarity -- that answer says "There are a lot of questions tagged [tag:table]. The [tag:table] wiki has a list of other tags you should be using for every scenario instead of table. It would take too much time to go retag them all, so it isn't worth doing." If I have that interpretation right, isn't [tag:table] a prime candidate to get rid of now that the cleanup effort is manageable?

Comment: Well, apparently someone has already been doing it, so I'm sure it will continue getting done. Why would they stop with only a couple thousand left after doing 20,000+? *shrugs*

Comment: I'll add an answer [probably later](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43302509#43302509), but for [staters, people have been systematically removing the tag overtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%E6%B1%A4%E8%8E%B1%E6%81%A9?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=625). There were [18,315 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198024/can-we-start-cleaning-up-table-tag-and-burninate-it-asap) when it was first proposed.

Comment: Well, you seem to understand the difference between a burninate request and a retag request as per the comments above. A burninate request is explicitly for deleting a tag without retagging, which clearly shouldn't be done here...

Comment: @animuson The community has been using the burniate tag to indicate general cleanup of tag https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination, I guess it is not directly related to your tool anymore. At this point I'm actually not sure what the actual difference is. That in the end you don't use your tools?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I was reading that page when you posted this. I'm back to the territory of confused as to which this is, because that process sounds ideal for this tag.

Comment: @PetterFriberg We probably should have gotten out in front of the terminology thing. To be honest, I've grown kind of sick of hearing the word "burninate" anyways. Maybe we should just combine the two tags together at some point...

Comment: @animuson that smells like a new meta post, I'd be interested in weighing in because the distinction isn't as clear as I had previously thought

Comment: @MoxieBall Do us a favor and don't retag closed questions. That kicks them into the reopen queue. If you remove or close all of the questions a mod can delete the closed ones and that burninates the tag

Comment: @Machavity my apologies, did that one rather absentmindedly

Comment: Wow!  Brian's devotion is phenomenal, after cleaning a tag with 200-300 questions about half incorrectly using it as a metatag I was totally drained and had no desire to do something similar ever again.

Comment: It's called gardening. Just a few weeds every day...